# Downloading syms package on macOS High Sierra

Tags: locale, octave, symbolic-math, macos-high-sierra

I am having trouble in downloading syms package for Octave.
I have already downloaded the package from this link: https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/ and added it to my load directory path.
I also installed SymPy in my terminal.
However, when I input this in my Octave command terminal:

```
pkg install -forge symbolic
```

This pops up:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LANG = "en_PH.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

I am really unfamiliar with all these terms. I hope someone can explain to me what to do in simpler words. Thank you!